# How to connect to wireless network via WPS with hidden SSID in Windows?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ssid, wps

I know how to connect to a WiFi network with hidden SSID on Windows XP, Vista, 7 or 8.

When new devices come into the network I prefer to do it via WPS. But I can do it only if I set the SSID to broadcast. If the SSID is hidden, I don't know how to connect using WPS.

Answer (score -1):

In Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center, there will be an option to `Set up a new connection or network` at the bottom half of the page. (Network and Sharing Center will, in the main window, display the networks you are connected to at the top, and then `Set up a new connection or network` and `Troubleshoot problems` below.

Click on that, and then when it prompts you to `Choose a connection option`, select `Manually connect to a hidden network`, then click `Next`. It will prompt you for your SSID, security type, and security key. Fill these in as appropriate, and then just click through.

Comment: Please, read carefully. Title and description say "using WPS"